# How to deal with frequent classes?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, classification, weka, supervised-learning

I'm working on a classification task in Weka and got the problem that my class to predict has one value that is very frequent (about 85%). This leads to a lot of learning algorithms just predicting this frequent value of this class for a new dataset.

How can I deal with this problem? Does it just mean that I didn't find features that work well enough in predicting something better? Or is there something specific I can do to solve this problem?

I guess this is a pretty common problem, but I was not able to find a solution to it here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools for multiclass imbalanced classification in statistical packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877153/tools-for-multiclass-imbalanced-classification-in-statistical-packages), [How to deal with low frequency examples in classification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618532/how-to-deal-with-low-frequency-examples-in-classification) and several other questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast help! These questions give me hints about how to name that problem (and how to solve it).
And sorry if I mix up the terms. Weka uses them in a different way than I orginally learned them the first time.

Comment: Yeah, Weka has a somewhat strange use of terms. (And the broader ML community has problem picking its terminology sometimes...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "SMOTE" your data.  First figure out how many more instances of the minority case you need.  In my case I wanted to get around a 50/50 ratio so I needed to over sample by 1300 percent.  This tutorial will help if you are using the GUI: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w14ha2Fmg6U  If you are doing this from the command line using Weka, the following command will get you going:

```
#Weka 3.7.7
java weka.Run -no-scan weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE \
-c last -K 25 -P 1300.0 -S 1 -i input.arff  -o  output.arff
```

The -K option is the number of neighbors to take into account when smoting the data.  The default is 5, but 25 worked best for my dataset.

Comment: Thanks! As an addition to the solution: The meta classifier FilteredClassifier assists doing so (meta/FilteredClassifier). Especially when trying out how much over-sampling is needed (how much artifical datasets have to be added).